# Run all SQL queries in a folder and its sub folders

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run several hundreds queries that are located in many folders. All the folders are located under one "Master" directory.

I have the following batch code that allows me to run all the queries in one folder:

```
    for %%G in (*.sql) do psql -U postgres -f "%%G" Satellites_Updated
pause
```

I am unsure how to make this batch file recursive so I can also check sub folders.

I have the following code, which does not work (only prints the current directory in the cmd window, then exits).

```
     @echo off
        call :treeProcess
        goto :eof

:treeProcess

        for %%G in (*) do (

        if exist %1\* (

            cd %1
            call :treeProcess
            cd ..
        )
        else (
            psql -U postgres -f "%%G" Satellites_Updated
        )
      )
      exit \b
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
   for /r %%G in (*.sql) do psql -U postgres -f "%%G" Satellites_Updated
   pause
```

When it is so simple sometimes ...